# Get lat long from the CoordinateReferenceSystem of shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

This is the GCS from the shapefile

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", 
  DATUM["D_WGS_1984", 
    SPHEROID["World_Geodetic_System_of_1984_GEM_10C", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
  AXIS["Latitude", NORTH]]
```

and this is the max bounds

```
ReferencedEnvelope[3349092.9261588315 : 3376880.6375707085, 3388275.1707543265 : 3443415.5516665876]
```

I added this transformation, but didn't worked

```
    static public double[] reverse(double degrees) {
        double sign = Math.signum(degrees);
        if (sign == 0.0) {
            sign = 1.0f;
        }
        double[] ret = new double[3];
        degrees = Math.abs(degrees);
        ret[0] = Math.floor(degrees);
        double mins = degrees - ret[0];
        ret[1] = Math.floor(mins * 60);
        ret[2] = ((mins * 60 - ret[1])) * 60;
        ret[0] *= sign;
        return ret;
    }
```

How can I get normal lat long from this?

Comment: By transformation.

Comment: I applied the transformation as above but didn't worked

Comment: Why don't you use the native transformation tool?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: those coordinates can't be in that CRS so you need to go back to the data source and find out what the projection actually is

Comment: This is prj file
`PROJCS["something",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["World_Geodetic_System_of_1984_GEM_10C",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",4000000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",4000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",80.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",12.4729444000001],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",35.1728055499991],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",24.0],UNIT["METER",1.0]]`

Comment: Your "something" is "WGS_1984_Lambert_Conformal_Conic", which means that your data has meter as unit, and you cannot extract lat long directly with the code provided. You need to reproject your data first to lat long.